# ASP.NET MVC forms authentication error with Safari browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am using forms authentication in my ASP.NET MVC web application, it was working fine on live server running on Windows 2016. But when we deployed the same website to a Windows Server 2022, Safari browser login cookies are being flushed from the request.

I am sending forms authentication cookie in response but not receiving it in the next request.

This is my login code:

```
var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie("username", true);

var oldTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            oldTicket.Version,
            oldTicket.Name,
            oldTicket.IssueDate,
            oldTicket.Expiration,
            oldTicket.IsPersistent,
            "Role1,Role2");

if (!FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
{
    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(encryptedTicket, true);
}
else
{
    cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

After this code, I also added the following

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
        new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity("username"),
        "Role1,Role2");
```

And when I try to get it in next request, it's null in `global.asax`:

```
// It's null here
var authCookies = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```

With Google Chrome, it's working perfectly fine, only Safari is causing this issue. I tested with iPhone and Mac Safari browsers and see the same issue.

Comment: This may help you
https://brockallen.com/2019/01/11/same-site-cookies-asp-net-core-and-external-authentication-providers/

Comment: I downgraded my Windows Server which resolved the issue. 
I did all with cookies, [Same, Lax, None] secure but nothing helped. so after wasting two days finally decided to downgrade the windows server which resolved the issue like magic.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything to identify the issue, But I was unable to figure out this issue. Then finally I downgraded my Windows server from 2022 to 2019 which resolved the issue right away.